# How to retrieve configuration 'Options' instances from a ModelBinder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a custom ModelBinder and I need to retrieve the MvcJsonOptions config instance that was set in Startup from

```
services.AddMvc(options => {...})
.AddJsonOptions(options => { 

//I need this 'option' instance from my model binder 

});
```

Not sure whether I should retrieve them from the service provider, what would be the best approach to retrieve them?

Comment: Who said it's not retrievable via DI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dunno who told you it's not retrievable, but all configurations are registered via DI, even `MvcOptions` and `MvcJsonOptions`, as you can clearly see on the source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/DependencyInjection/MvcJsonMvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L33)

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions(
    this IMvcBuilder builder,
    Action<MvcJsonOptions> setupAction)
{
    if (builder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
    }

    if (setupAction == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(setupAction));
    }

    // configure registers it with the DI system
    builder.Services.Configure(setupAction);
    return builder;
}
```

That being said, all you need to do is inject `IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>` where ever you need it and access `options.Value` property to get the instance.

#### Update

As pointed in the comments, `IModelBinderProvider` isn't supposed to have dependencies injected. `IModelBinderProvider` is only used to create the binder and should have no external dependencies.

```
public class MyBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (/* some condition to identify your model */)
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(MyBinder));

        return null;
    }
}
```

and `MyBinder` should have the dependencies:

```
public class MyBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly MvcJsonOptions jsonOptions;

    public MyBinder(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> options)
    {
        jsonOptions = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Your binding logic here
        ...
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. One remaining problem is that the ModelBinderProvider  is created before the serviceProvider is built, and before the MvcJsonOption is declared. Is there a way to retrieve the serviceProvider later on, globally?

Comment: ModelBinderProvider shouldn't require any external dependencies. ModelBinderProvider is only used to create and return Binder. The binder should be the one which receives the dependencies. You should return `return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(MyBinder));` to return Binders which require dependencies injected

Comment: Yep, literally just published the custom model binder doc a few days ago. Good answer.